# Trailing hyphens are ignored in tag suggestions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, suggested-tags

Trailing hyphens are ignored in tag suggestions.

Example from https://travel.stackexchange.com, tested in Chrome for Android:

[image]

Typing `la-` should have brought up `la-paz` instead of the five suggestions present on the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

We intentionally ignore hyphens when searching for matching tags to make it easier for users to find relevant tags. There are a lot of situations out there where not everyone agrees on the use of a hyphen within a word or phrase, and users should not need to deal with the question of whether or not to include the hyphen in order to find the tag they need.

Including the hyphen at any point in the search potentially makes it harder for users to find a tag. So, you'll simply need to type out more of the term in order to find more specific results.

Comment: This is so annoying! As it requires to type 2 extra characters in the search field, the hyphen and the following character. Where in most cases just adding the hyphen would make the desired tag appear in the search results.

Comment: @Luuklag I had written a comment opining that the trailing hyphen is the most important (exactly to prevent the time waster you mentioned), but my comment got removed....

Comment: @Luuklag It only requires one additional character. You can just type the next letter and it will appear, since hyphens are ignored. I do this all the time for the status tags (e.g. typing "statusc" brings up the "status-completed" tag).